# predict new data by pre-trained model in tensor-flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, prediction

I trained a LSTM model in tensor-flow and I want to predict new data based on it. However, I keep getting an error I can't understand:

This is the model:

```python
def __init__(self , snapshot_dir, save_dir ):
    self.save_dir = save_dir
    self.snapshot_dir =  snapshot_dir
    self.learning_rate = params["learning_rate"]
    self.training_steps = params["training_steps"]
    self.batch_size = params["batch_size"]
    self.display_step = params["display_step"]
    self.num_input = params["num_input"]  
    self.timesteps = params["timesteps"]  
    self.num_hidden = params["num_hidden"]  
    self.num_classes = params["num_classes"] 
    self.define_graph()

def define_graph(self):

    self.X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, self.timesteps, self.num_input], name="X")
    self.Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, self.num_classes], name="Y")
    self.weights = {'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.num_hidden, self.num_classes]))}
    self.biases = {'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.num_classes]))}

def RNN(self):

    x = tf.unstack(self.X, self.timesteps, 1)
    lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(self.num_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, reuse=tf.get_variable_scope().reuse)
    outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x , dtype=tf.float32)
    return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], self.weights['out']) + self.biases['out']

def run(self, X_train, y_train):

    logits = self.RNN()
    self.prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="prediction")
    loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        logits=logits, labels=self.Y))
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)
    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(self.prediction, 1), tf.argmax(self.Y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:

        sess.run(init)
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        for step in range(1, self.training_steps + 1):
            start_idx = random.randint(0, len(X_train) - self.timesteps - 1)
            batch_x = self.generate_x_batch_data(start_idx, X_train, self.batch_size)
            batch_y = self.generate_y_batch_data(start_idx, y_train, self.batch_size)

            sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={self.X: batch_x, self.Y: batch_y})
        saver.save(sess, self.save_dir, global_step=step)
```

And the prediction part:

```python
    sess = tf.Session()
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("{}.meta".format(self.newest_snapshot))
    saver.restore(sess, self.newest_snapshot)
    X_as_batch = self.aux.generate_x_batch_data(0,X, len(X))
    pred = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name("prediction").outputs[0]
    feed_dict = {tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name('X').outputs[0]: X_as_batch}
    prediction = sess.run(pred,
                          feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

the shape of `X_as_batch` is as expected by `pred` (it's shape is `[5126, 60, 39]`  and the shape of `pred` is `[?, 60, 39]`)

But I get the error

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value
>   for placeholder tensor 'X_1' with dtype float and shape [?,1024]
>   [[Node: X_1 = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,1024],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

What might be the reason?

Comment: Show us your model

Comment: @Maxim added in the original post

Comment: The placeholders are still missing. Try `graph.get_tensor_by_name("X:0")` and `graph.get_tensor_by_name("prediction:2")`

Comment: @Maxim Sorry, added

Comment: What confuses me here is that error message says about `X_1`, not `X`. Which hints there's one more `X` somewhere

Comment: Nope, I double-checked it now... no additional X

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have a `X_1` tensor is that you have restored a graph while your old graph still exists.  In order to avoid having two TensorFlow variables which are both called `X`, the new one gets an `_1` appended to it.

I can't be sure because you haven't included all your code, but if you're doing all your work in one execution you might not need to restore anything.  Alternatively, you might just need to restore the checkpoint file that `saver` creates, using something like `saver.restore(sess, './model.ckpt')`, with `'./model.ckpt'` replaced by the path to your `ckpt` file.